# magit, understand magit-blame

Tags: magit

When I enter magit-blame it shows the following lines.

```
jihae                2020-04-07 14:51 불필요한 파일 삭제, yarn 빠진 부분 추가, public path

Eugene Kim           2020-06-04 17:50 config
process.env.__DEV__ = isEnvProduction
Eugene Kim           2020-03-14 21:43 web start
```

Although the `process.env.__DEV__ = isEnvProduction` line is added by `jihae`

If I do `magit-blame-addition` on the `process.env.__DEV__ = isEnvProduction` the lines change to the following

```
jihae                2020-04-07 14:51 불필요한 파일 삭제, yarn 빠진 부분 추가, public path
const isEnvDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const isEnvProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

process.env.__DEV__ = isEnvProduction
Eugene Kim           2020-04-09 15:07 __DEV__
```

I'm trying to understand what magit is telling me,
on first invocation, the line in question is added by `Eugene Kim` and if i do `magit-blame-addition` (not sure what exactly it does) it shows the line is added by `jihae`.

What is going on?

Additionally, if I do `magit-blame-quit` multiple times after the `magit-blame-addition`, I end up with modified file content that I'm visiting..

(From file A, if I do magit-blame, magit-blame-addition, magit-blame-quit, mgit-blame-quit, file A is different from what I started with..)

Comment: Do you seem to get the same information if you `magit-blame-cycle-style` (type `c`)?  Does `C-x v g` show you different information?

Comment: How do you "enter magit-blame"? Mention the keys you press.